# Execute content of buffer as vimscript

Tags: vimscript, buffers

I have a `nofile` buffer that contains vimscript, and I want to execute it.  However, `:so %`  will not work because it requires a saved file, not a buffer.  Is there a vim command to do this by default?  If not, is it possible to create a function which does the same things?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can yank the whole buffer with `ggyG` or `:%y` and execute it with `:@"`.

In short:

```
:%y|@"<CR>
```

Used in a mapping:

```
nnoremap <key> :%y|@"<CR>
```

Used in a flexible command that works on the whole buffer by default or an optional range:

```
command! -bar -range=% Foo execute <line1> . ',' . <line2> . 'y|@"'
```

Comment: you have a missing colon in first command.

Comment: Also, this does clobber the `"` register.  I imagine you could use another register if you wanted to, or you could just save the `"` register and restore it afterwards.